# What Plugins of wordpress use this site?

Tags: string, wordpress, random, plugins, hash

I'm new here hello to all , i want to ask you what plugins of wordpress use this site with random string after slash url /? site is : 
http://freaktoday.us/
after refresh http://freaktoday.us/**?tem=832** change and every refresh random text changed how they created

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This site may be using a plugin in like [WP Hashed IDs](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-hashed-ids/) based on [hashids library](http://hashids.org/php/).

Also, WordPress has a built-in function `wp_unique_post_slug()`and can be referenced in the [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unique_post_slug).